# Authentication Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a website where i have a event module, where the users can maintain their own events.

At the same time i have a Facebook Page(not app) and i would really like to create/update/delete the events from my website directly to Facebook.

I have the following working:

```
        FacebookClient clientApp = new FacebookClient(token);
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("name", currentEvent.HeadLine);
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        parameters.Add("start_time", currentEvent.StartDateTime);
        parameters.Add("end_time", currentEvent.EndDateTime);
        parameters.Add("location", currentEvent.Location);
        parameters.Add("description", currentEvent.Description);
        var postResult = (IDictionary<string, object>)currentClient.Post("pageid/events", parameters);
```

the accesstoken used is from my facebook login, so if that expires the system fails.

Any other way or can i get a newer expiring accesstoken.

Regards Keld

regards Keld

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, one is to request the permission offline access from Facebook when you obtain the token.  This gives you a token that never expires (unless the user explicitly removes access for your app.

The second way is to handle exceptions from the callback of the method.  In the handling code you detect a token expired exception and redirect users to the appropriate login page to get a new token.  You can then re-try the event update.

Comment: to publish events to Facebook Page(not App) i need the pages access-token which expires every 2 hour(default) i need to make the publish from my own facebook account so that the users of my website doesnt have to log into facebook, but publish via my account

Comment: Can you get the page's access token from your user access token? One workaround would be to have a web browser control on the server side and populate the username and password boxes and simulate clicking login, it would be an unsupported technique though.